# Enforcing immutability of Kubernetes custom resource spec fields

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-operator

I'm using the Kubernetes golang operator sdk to implement an operator that manages RabbitMQ queues. I'm wondering if there's a way for k8s to enforce immutability of particular spec fields on my custom resource. I have the following golang struct which represents a rabbitMQ queue and some parameters to have it bind to a rabbitMQ exchange:

```golang
type RmqQueueSpec struct {
    VHost string `json:"vhost,required"`
    Exchange string `json:"exchange,required"`
    RoutingKey string `json:"routingKey"`
    SecretConfig map[string]string `json:"secretConfig"`
}
```

The reason why I want immutability, specifically for the `VHost` field, is because it's a parameter that's used to namespace a queue in rabbitMQ. If it were changed for an existing deployed queue, the k8s reconciler will fail to query rabbitMQ for the intended queue since it will be querying with a different vhost (effectively a different namespace), which could cause the creation of a new queue or an update of the wrong queue.

There are a few alternatives that I'm considering such as using the required ObjectMeta.Name field to contain both the concatenated vhost and the queuename to ensure that they are immutable for a deployed queue. Or somehow caching older specs within the operator (haven't figured out exactly how to do this yet) and doing a comparison of the old and current spec in the reconciler returning an error if `VHost` changes. However neither of these approaches seem ideal. Ideally if the operator framework could enforce immutability on the `VHost` field, that would be a simple approach to handling this.

Comment: Unrelated, but feel free to swipe some code from ours https://github.com/Ridecell/ridecell-operator/tree/master/pkg/controller/rabbitmq_vhost :)

Comment: thank you, it's always helpful to have some example code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not yet available to CRDs. Our approach is generally to use the object name as the default name of the object being controlled (vhost name in this case) so it just naturally works out okay.

Comment: This is possible with CRDs, but you need to create and register a ValidatingAdmissionWebhook to do it, it can't be enforced just through the spec.

Comment: Yeah, the feature went GA in 1.17 I think. Or somewhere around there.

Comment: This is no longer true, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

This validation is possible by using the [ValidatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook) with future support coming via CRD's OpenAPI validation.

- https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/1587
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65973

Comment: Are there any concrete tutorials for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible now, even without a ValidationAdmissionWebhook using [CEL Transition Rules](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/09/29/enforce-immutability-using-cel/).

If you're using controller-gen, you can do this:

```golang
type RmqQueueSpec struct {
    // +kubebuilder:validation:XValidation:rule="self == oldSelf",message="VHost is immutable"
    VHost string `json:"vhost,required"`
    Exchange string `json:"exchange,required"`
    RoutingKey string `json:"routingKey"`
    SecretConfig map[string]string `json:"secretConfig"`
}
```